# Read specific columns of multiple .xlsx files into R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have multiple .xlsx files in my project file. I can easily read them all in via:

```
library(readxl)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
```

However, when I try to bind into one data.frame, using:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- bind_rows(df.list, .id = "id")
```

I am encountering issues because the column types are different. Specifically, I get `Error: Can't combine 1$START_1 <datetime<UTC>> and 2$START_` .`

I think I can overcome this by calling out specific columns that I need, which are all numeric and don't contain any `datetime` issues. Specifically, I want `[,12:22]` from each data.frame in the list. How do I do this, preferably using dplyr?

Ideally, I would also have `id` be the filename of each .xlsx read in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer a `tidyverse` way you can use `map_df`/`map_dfr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readxl)
map_df(file.list, ~read_excel(.x) %>% select(12:22), .id = "id")
```

Similar to your attempt with `lapply` if you want id as filename instead of number.

```
dplyr::bind_rows(sapply(file.list, function(x) read_excel(x)[12:22], 
                 simplify = FALSE), .id = 'id')
```

Comment: All hail the `tidyverse`, thank you! How do I also get `id` to be the filename? I'll edit my original post.

Comment: You can use `sapply` with `simplify = FALSE` in that case. Check updated answer.